# Calender Week number fixing in Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, calendar

How to fix the CW number shown in Outlook calendar (for macOS Ventura 13.6)? As you can see from below image, the calendar number for the Oct 09 - 13 week shows as 42, where as it is CW41 in actual world.

[image: CW Picture]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like something which can be defined in Outlook Options/Preferences. What have you tried so far?

Comment: So in my organization, changing the start day is not possible. I just downloaded Itsycal and gave this problem a 'pass'.